# How to get currentReceiveAddress from Bitcoinj wallet without network connection?

Tags: java, bitcoin, wallet, bitcoinj

We are using [bitcoinj](https://bitcoinj.github.io/) to work with bitcoin wallets. Protobuf serialized [Wallet](https://bitcoinj.github.io/working-with-the-wallet) body is stored in database as byte array.

As far as I'm concerned, there is no need to connect to bitcoin network to get [receive address](https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.13/org/bitcoinj/core/Wallet.html#currentReceiveAddress--), because it is calculated somehow from keys, that are stored in [Wallet](https://bitcoinj.github.io/working-with-the-wallet) entity.

So my question - is it possible to deserialize protobuf to bitcoinj [Wallet](https://bitcoinj.github.io/working-with-the-wallet) entity without any network activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getBitcoinAddress() {
    val seedCode = "yard impulse luxury drive today throw farm pepper survey wreck glass federal"
    val wallet = Wallet.fromSeed(
        NetworkParameters.fromID(NetworkParameters.ID_MAINNET),
        DeterministicSeed(seedCode, null, "", 0L)
    )
    val changeAddress = wallet.currentChangeAddress()
    val freshAddress = wallet.freshReceiveAddress()
    val currentAddress = wallet.currentReceiveAddress()
    System.out.println(
      "currentReceiveAddress$currentAddress 
       freshAddress$freshAddress 
       changeAddress $changeAddress"
      )**strong text**
    }
```

**Generate A Wallet from mnemonic or seed, then you can get the address. And, yes it is offline**